# Wordpress blog integration not working: Error Establishing a Database Connection

Tags: php, wordpress, integration, opencart

I am in the process of integrating wordpress with opencart.

I have succesfully installed wordpress at mydomain.com/wp , it works fine and I can access everything as needed.

I have this, placed just before the start of my opencart header tag on a specific page.

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

and I am receiving an "Error Establishing a Database Connection" error, clearly it is finding wp-blog-header, wordpress at mydomain.com/wp is also working fine and thus connecting to the DB which is why I am confused as to what the problem is. I have a feeling it could be related to this specifically the **FILE** in wp-config but I am not sure?

```
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

Comment: In that header I would define the `ABSPATH` to point directly to a WP installation, like `define('ABSPATH', '/my/webroot/path/wp/');` - hmm? It then should use this defined and do not *re-define* the `ABSPATH` after wp-config is included...

Comment: does dirname(__FILE__) just refer to the current file calling it, or wp-config itself?

Comment: `dirname(__FILE__)` will return the absolute path to the concrete (current) file, that means to Your header file (I do not know whether it is a controller or template file...).

Comment: I tried just writing the absolute path, did nothing. used echo getcwd(); ..none of this makes sense  ...

Also @shadyyx the `__FILE__` is in mysite.com/wp/wp-config.php , not my header which is mysite.com/blog

Comment: Did you try using the blog modules available in the market for creating a full-fledged blog in OpenCart? That must be easy and less time consuming. Here is the one if you like to consider that option - http://www.fmeaddons.com/opencart/blog-news-articles-module.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the DB_PASSWORD conflicts with one that OpenCart apparently uses this. Changing DB_PASSWORD to DP_WPPASSWD (or a name of your choosing) solves the error. However I now have another error.

Fatal error: Call to a member function main() on a non-object in /xxx/wp/wp-includes/functions.php on line 779